# Peut-on utiliser « les », « lui » et « y » simultanément dans une même phrase ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

Peut-on utiliser « les », « lui » et « y » simultanément dans une même phrase ?

Par exemple :

> J'ai vu Ardalan dans le parc hier soir.
>
> Je lui ai dit les nouvelles.

Peut-il devenir :

> Je les lui y ai dites.

Avec *les* pour *les nouvelles*, *y* pour *le parc* et *lui* pour *Ardalan*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Il me semble que c'est trop. Je ne me souviens pas avoir jamais entendu une telle accumulation de pronoms, et indépendamment de la justesse grammaticale de l'expression, cela nuirait terriblement à la compréhension de la phrase.

La pronominalisation des deux compléments d'objets (direct et indirect) est possible et courante, mais se cumule mal avec celle du complément de lieu.

*« Je les lui ai dites là-bas. »* sonnerait bien mieux si tu ne veux pas répéter l'élément de lieu sous sa forme complète (*dans le parc*).

Answer (score 10):

Le véritable problème, ici, c'est l'utilisation du pronom *y* pour « dans le parc ». La phrase « Je lui y ai dit les nouvelles » n'est pas naturelle non plus. *Y* s'emploie plus facilement pour une destination que pour un complément circonstanciel.

Il va sans dire que pour faciliter la compréhension, l'utilisation de trois pronoms est peu recommandable. Mais, par exemple, en réponse à une requête claire comme celle-ci, cela ne me choquerait pas outre mesure :

> — Peux-tu envoyer ces colis à son domicile ?
>   — Je les lui y envoie tout de suite !

Comment: +1 : L'expression est tout à fait correcte en effet.

Comment: L'expression me paraît effet tout à fait correcte grammaticalement, mais la prononcer me semble complexe. N'avons-nous rien pour nous faciliter la vie dans ce genre de liaison ? (Petite note accessoire : « lui » est introduit un peu artificiellement dans l'exemple, il ne reprend rien de la question. ;) )

Answer (score 1):

La réponse simple est: **oui**, selon moi, ça se dit (grammaticalement correct) mais on préférera une autre formule moins confuse.

Comment: Bienvenue sur [FR.SE](http://french.stackexchange.com/) ! Merci de participer mais je te conseille pour tes futurs réponses de : 1. citer des sources et les liens correspondants si possible; 2. vérifier que ta réponse apporte quelque chose qui n'a pas été dit et 3. relire ta question et la mettre un minimum en forme. (tu n'as pas fermé ta parenthèse, tu mets des points et majuscules au lieu de virgules.)